# Highcharts chartWidth no longer works with chart.getSVG()

Tags: highcharts

Correct me if I'm wrong but I could have sworn chart.chartWidth used to return the exact  width attribute as returned by getSVG().
I'll explain.
Say I target a div that forces a chart to render with the following  as read via view source.
    `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="270" height="300">`

Now if I call `chart.highcharts().chartWidth` I'll get 270. Great!
But if I then call `chart.highcharts().getSVG()` I'll get this is an opening
    `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="600">`

I've been using and adding to an export function that will combine multiple charts into a single  and I typically need to do some scaling to get it to look nice. The scale is dependent on the originally rendered size, not the default and now it's causing a huge problem.

Shouldn't getSVG return svg representing the chart as it appears in html?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [sourceWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.sourceWidth) or [scale](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.scale) parameter?

Comment: I'm using a manual export which is basically a temporary form element that submits a huge manually created svg string to highcharts server. It doesn't take sourceWidth or scale in account.
I found a fix however. If you pass the chartWidth and chartHeight to getSVG() you'll get a piece of SVG that matches what's currently in the browser.
    `var chart = myChart.highcharts();
    var svg = chart.getSVG({chart:{width:chart.chartWidth, height:chart.chartHeight}});`

Comment: Thank you Joel, I had the same problem and can confirm this works:
chart.getSVG({chart:{width:chart.chartWidth, height:chart.chartHeight}});

Comment: Thank you Joel +1, works for me for getting this issue