# How to add more columns to this JS PNG converter? [Highcharts]

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I'm using the following code

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/

Basically it works fine for my purpose, but it produces one long image in my case (in some circumstances I have an image like 300x7000 px!)

In the code is this function:

```
 $.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

        top += chart.chartHeight;
        width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

        svgArr.push(svg);
    });
```

I'm trying to work out how to make it so that the graphs are stacked side by side for 3 widths, and then it goes onto the next line.

Sort of like this (with X being a graph):

X X X

X X X

Instead of:

X

X

X

Does anybody have any idea how I can modify this code to do this? I don't know where to begin. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence it just comes down to logic and moving the individual SVGs correctly in relation to eachother. The essential line of the `Highcharts.getSVG` code, as you've pointed out, is:

```
svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
```

Below ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/2333/)) I've made a crude example of how you can do it, and all it comes down to is logic and keeping track of width (and "columns") before moving to a new height ("row"):

```
Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {
    var svgArr = [],
        columns = 3, // How many columns you want
        top = 0,
        width = 0,
        currentTopMax = 0;
        currentWidth = 0,
        currentColumn = 0,
        index = 0;

    $.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
        var svg = chart.getSVG({chart:{width:chart.chartWidth, height:chart.chartHeight}});
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(' + currentWidth + ',' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

        currentWidth += chart.chartWidth;

        currentTopMax = Math.max(currentTopMax, chart.chartHeight);
        width = Math.max(width, currentWidth);
        index++;

        if(++currentColumn % columns == 0) {
            top += currentTopMax;
            currentTopMax = 0;
            currentWidth = 0;
        }

        svgArr.push(svg);
    });

    if(index % columns != 0)
        top += currentTopMax;

    return '<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
};
```

Also note that your original code had a problem with the `chart.getSVG` getting the incorrect width for each individual chart, leaving some blank space. The original line was:

```
var svg = chart.getSVG();
```

Which has been replaced with:

```
var svg = chart.getSVG({chart:{width:chart.chartWidth, height:chart.chartHeight}});
```

Credit to Joel Stransky for [finding that fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537628/highcharts-chartwidth-no-longer-works-with-chart-getsvg#comment25537192_17548307).

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I needed. Thanks Halvor, very helpful!